# How can I know if an email sent using PHP was read?

Tags: php, email

I already have a script that delivers the email to a particular email address. I embedded also an image tag that serve as checker if the email was opened. Now my problem is, since I am sending mail with *CC* I cannot detect if the **CC** or **To** is the one who open the mail.

Please if you already have experience this kind of problem and you found a solution, your help is much appreciated.

I googled it already and no answer found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a header in the email message. You can read more about `disposition header` [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798).

```
Disposition-Notification-To: you@youremail.com
```

If you happen to use `phpmailer` you can use following configuration:

```
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'you@youremail.com';
```

As another option you can compose an `HTML` email message, which loads a hidden image from your server. Something like following. To hide the image, set its width and height to `1*1` px so it doesn't show up in the email.

```
<img src='http://www.yourserver.com/mailcheck.php?user=123'>
```

If your `mailcheck.php` is requested you know that it was requested from email by user with id `123`.

I don't think there is a way to track each cc recipients unless you program on the mail server level. Even the image technique is a hack this functionality is not provided by the mail server.

Long answer short, if you want to track each recepients send individual emails to each of the and follow the above technique.

Comment: Yes sir I am using similar to the option mentioned, what I did is, I add 1x1 pixel image that serve as a tracker <img src='http://www.yourserver.com/mailcheck.php?user=123'>, now my issue is how to track if the one who opened the mail is the **primary/to** recipient or the **cc** email address.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that unless you program on the mail server level.

Comment: Thank you sir, your help is much appreciated